# Export wordcloud2 as html automatically?

Tags: r, plot

Is there a way to export word cloud generated by `wordcloud2` package as `html` automatically without having to manually click on `Export` > `Save as Web Page` (in RStudio)? Something like saving pdfs with `pdf` and images with `png`?

Here is the code to generate sample wordcloud

```
require(wordcloud2)
df = head(demoFreq,50)
wordcloud2(df)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require(wordcloud2)
df       <- head(demoFreq, 5)
my_cloud <- wordcloud2(df)
my_path  <- htmltools::html_print(my_cloud) # saves html in temp directory
print(my_path) # the location of the html file.
```

It would be best to swiftly move this file to a more permanent home.